# django package for accessing original instance values

Tags: python, django

I want to override the save() method of my model and check changes to some of the fields:

```
def save(self):
    if self.counter != self.original_counter: # that's what I want
        ...
```

I saw this question was asked before and the answer was to get the object from the db and compare the db value with the current value:

```
def save(self):
    original = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
    if self.counter != original.counter:
        ...
```

but that's a waste of a db query, it's easy to get what I want if on every instance initialization the `__init__` method will initialize 2 attributes for each field - `obj.<attr>` and also `obj.original_<attr>`, do I need to implement it myself or is there a django package that can do it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way you can get the original values like that. Even if you implement the pseudo `original_*` fields yourself, you'd end up doing a `MyModel.objects.get(...)` anyways.

The issue is that inside the `save()` method, the object has already been saved. So you see the new values. There is no way to see the original values without querying the database.